# Rails ActiveRecord, User ID getting a List of datatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Not sure if this question is clear as i am trying find right word for clear on the Question

I am working on the Rails Active Record as trying to get a listing of data which own by User.

At the moment the pages display as you can see Screenshot "more equipment own by Ashford tools Hire
[image]

it's should show 5 different tools but I seem cannot get it, I am able to get all data in the display but unable to get the user list of tools, seems I have missed one or two small things

here is the code I wrote.

```
      <!-- More equipment from owner -->
  <div class="row">
    <h3>More equipment own by <strong><%= @tool.user.company %></strong></h3>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
          <%= image_tag @tool.images.first, class:"imgnear" if  @tool.images.attached? %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= link_to @tool.brand, target: :_blank %><br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried 'each do' function but keeping getting error

I have done current_user but it not practically

```
<!-- More equipment from owner -->
  <div class="row">
    <h3>More equipment own by <strong><%= @tool.user.company %></strong></h3>
    <% current_user.tools.each do |tool| %>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading preview">
          <%= image_tag tool.images.first, class:"imgnear" if  tool.images.attached? %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= link_to tool.brand, tool, target: :_blank %><br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

while in the Tools Controller

```
  def index
    @tools = current_user.tools

  end

  def new
    @tool = current_user.tools.build
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you display in that screen is `ToolsController#show` action, not a `ToolsController#index` action. Probably your `show` method looks like this:

```
def show
  @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
end
```

or similarly.

In order to have other tools displayed, you need to assign them to some variable inside the same controller action. What you can do is:

```
def show
  @tool = Tool.find(params[:id]) # or however that line looks
  @other_tools = @tool.user.tools.where("id != ?", @tool.id)
end
```

This way `@other_tools` will consist of all the tools belonging to owner of the selected tool, but it will exclude the selected tool (otherwise inside the "also owned by" you can see the same tool as displayed above the list)

One more thing, when you do `current_user.tools` in your view, you display the items owner by user who is logged in, not the user who owns the main displayed tool, you might not see the error if you log in as an owner, but if you log in as another user, you should see that the list shows wrong tools.

Comment: Perfect, i just knew it that should be in Tools controller, it not easy to work on own without any developer in the team.

Comment: I'm using  @owner_tools = @tool.user.tools.where("id != ?", @tool.id)